# Htaccess Rewrite Rules and Conditions

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have started yet another little project for personal uses, and I am setting up my web root htaccess file. I haven't touched this stuff for too long so I am having some issues with it.

I will show some examples of what I want to do because I don't know how to explain it well.
My webroot contains:

/index.php

/test/test.txt

If the url is example.com/home, it should output example.com/index.php?page=home. That is pretty easy to do and I don't have any issue with it. The issue starts with the existing files.
If the url is example.com/test or example.com/test/test.txt, I want it to output example.com/index.php?file=test or example.com/index.php?file=test/test.txt
These are the conditions and rules in my htaccess file (these are meant for the existing files only):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ - [S=1]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)$ /index.php?file=$1 [L,QSA]
```

However, when I enter example.com/test, it goes straight to the directory "test" and the same with example.com/test.txt - just displays the file.

First of all, is it alright to do this? And if so, how can I achieve this?
Thanks in advance!

P.S. How do I log the processing of my rewrite rules? I found that I can do this by modifying LogLevel in httpd.conf. I had it set to LogLevel alert rewrite:trace6, but the errorlog doesn't seem to contain the logs I need.

Comment: You cannot rewrite every file to `index.php?file=` as `index.php` is also a file and so are css/js/images. You can probably rewrite few selected file extensions and rewrite them.

Comment: "if the url is `example.com/test`" - do you specifically want this without the trailing slash (where `/test` is a physical directory)? What if the user requests `/test/` (with a trailing slash)? Which is canonical? "when I enter `example.com/test`, it goes straight to the directory "test"" - not quite, you should be seeing a 301 redirect to `example.com/test/` first. "and the same with `example.com/test.txt` - just displays the file" - I assume you mean `/test/test.txt`?

Answer (score 0):

You have asked multiple questions, so this is a partial answer.

**Preventing Directory Listing**

For any folder that does not have index.php/html, if you do not want the contents listed, create a **.htaccess** file in that folder with the contents **Options -Indexes**

**Preventing File Execution**

For any folder that has files for reference (not meant to be executed or shown), change the permission to **750**  They can still be included or referenced server side.